# Replace a dictionary key from a list

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following list:

```
my_list= ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

My dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'source':{'new_key': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}
```

I would like to replace the `new_key` value in the dictionary with the list value `my_list` and I would like to get the following three dictionaries

```
{'source':{'aa': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}

{'source':{'bb': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}

{'source':{'cc': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}
```

I have tried the following

```
for i in my_list:
    my_dict ['source'][f'{i}'] = my_dict ['sources']['new_key']
    del my_dict ['source']['new_key']
```

Comment: You want 3 new dictionaries. Do you want the references to the dictionaries in a list or 3 different variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you create the dictionaries. What you do with them is up to you:

```
USE_DEEPCOPY = False # change as needed

if USE_DEEPCOPY:
    from copy import deepcopy
else:
    def deepcopy(v):
        return v

my_dict = {'source':{'new_key': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}

my_list= ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']

v = my_dict['source']['new_key']

for k in my_list:
    d = {'source':{k: deepcopy(v)}}
    print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'source': {'aa': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}
{'source': {'bb': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}
{'source': {'cc': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}
```

Comment: Without using `deepcopy`, all instances of `{'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}` represent the same object.

Comment: Indeed the variable v in your for loop will point to the same dict. Meaning the change of for example 'k1' will be affecting all three dicts.

Comment: I used this solution and works perfectly with my purpose.

Comment: On the grounds that this answer has been accepted, I can only assume that the new dictionaries should contain references to the original dictionary values rather than deep copies

Comment: @Hiwot That is a bad solution as a copy of the inner aprt isn't made, any modidicaiton to it would have side-effect, look my solution

Comment: @azro There is nothing in the original question to suggest that the dictionaries should be deep copied. In fact, it could be that the new dictionaries **should** contain references to the original. That would be a perfectly reasonable use-case

Comment: @azro I need to print out each dictionary separately instead of in all dictionaries in one list. Because my next step is parsing them to YAML separately. In that case, can you edit your answer to get the dictionaries separately?

Comment: @Hiwot try making any changes to one of them and see if that is what you really want.

Comment: @Hiwot if you don't know how to print each item of a list, I'd suggest you take some python tutorial. Also what do you mean "parsing them to yaml" ? Do you mean dumping them into yaml ? if so, different file ? that is unclear

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a deep copy of the dictionary to be able to modify each of them separately

```
from copy import deepcopy

my_list= ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
my_dict = {'source': {'new_key': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}

outdicts = {}

for l in my_list:
    outdicts[l] = deepcopy(my_dict)
    outdicts[l]['source'][l] = outdicts[l]['source'].pop('new_key')

print(f"{outdicts['aa'] = }")
print(f"{outdicts['bb'] = }")
print(f"{outdicts['cc'] = }")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you keep modifying the only existing dict instance, but you need new dict, and keep the original one as base

You need to make a deep copy of the original, modify it, and save it

```
from copy import deepcopy

my_list = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
my_dict = {'source': {'new_key': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}

result = []
for item in my_list:
    value = deepcopy(my_dict)
    value['source'][item] = value['source']['new_key']
    del value['source']['new_key']
    result.append(value)

print(result)
```

```
[{'source': {'aa': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}, 
 {'source': {'bb': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}},
 {'source': {'cc': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3}}}]
```

---

If there is only this change to do, you can simplify the code

```
result = []
for item in my_list:
    result.append({'source': {item: deepcopy(my_dict['source']['new_key'])}})
```